# PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, relational-database, oracle12c

I am building a statement to truncate my set of tables with data older than 30 days. To see data older than 30 days I use following sql statement and it executes successfully

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
    xyz --table name
    where 
    trunc(date_loaded_timestamp)<= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30;
```

Now I build my PL/SQL block as follows and gives me conversion error.

```
BEGIN
FOR c IN(
select b.table_name,b.column_name from all_tab_columns b where b.table_name like 'STG_%' and column_name ='DATE_LOADED_TIMESTAMP') LOOP
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('truncate table ' || c.table_name || ' where ' || trunc(c.column_name) || '<= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30');
END LOOP;
END;
```

After I run this block I get error

```
Error report -
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at line 4
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
```

I am confused as where did I convert character to number. I did not use any `TO_NUMBER` and the statement I used to select data worked why is PL/SQL not working?

Comment: Can you tell us which part throws this error? replace the execute immediate with a simple statement, and tell me if the error keep coming.

Comment: @sagi updated question with error I get on running PL/SQL block

Comment: I think I spotted an error, your query should be `('truncate table ' || c.table_name || ' where trunc(' || c.column_name || ') <= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30')` . That is if you want it to do the same as your SQL. Don't know if it will fix the error though.

Comment: @sagi thanks forgot that truncate does not work with conditions so I have to use `('Delete ' || c.table_name || ' where trunc(' || c.column_name || ')<= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30');`

Comment: Oh haha right, you can't do truncate with conditions :X Don't know how I've missed that.

Answer (score 0):

execute immediate code block can be like below.

```
execute immediate 'truncate table ' || c.table_name || ' where ' || trunc(c.column_name) || ' <= trunc(sysdate) - 30';
```